# MSComm32.ocx error code "438"

Tags: excel, vba

There is this code that I want to run on Excel 2013.

A button on the form runs this sub below:

```
Sub OpenPort()
With Worksheets("SerialPort").MSComm1
.CommPort = 5
.Settings = "9600,n,8,1"
.RThreshold = 1
.InBufferSize = 4096
.PortOpen = True
End With

End Sub
```

But when I run the code this message appears:

```
runtime error "438"
object doesn't support this property or method
```

I think I have a problem with the mscomm32.ocx file. But I added and registered this file into the syswow64 folder. The question is how can I run the MSComm control in an Excel file?

Comment: My last sentence may lead to a misunderstanding. I am using mscomm control in the program. But when I run the code I get this runtime error.

Comment: Is the error on the line `With Worksheets("SerialPort").MSComm1`? or on one of the property assignments?

Comment: yes it is on the    'With Worksheets("SerialPort").MSComm1'

Comment: Is the control actually named `MSComm1`? If you loop through the sheet's `OLEObjects` collection, do you find the object?

Comment: How can I make file visible or editible for you? Maybe it will be easier to check all at once. It really is a brief code.

Comment: Drop this in a Sub somewhere and run it. `Dim x As OLEObject: For Each x In Worksheets("SerialPort").OLEObjects: Debug.Print TypeName(x.Object): Next`.  What does it output?

Comment: I am sorry but what should I write instead of x in the code? Because nothing has changed in the code.

Comment: I mean there is nothing in the variable x

Comment: If it doesn't output anything, the control isn't embedded in the sheet. I'd see if you get any errors if you try to re-add it.

Comment: Any advice how I can embed the control in the sheet?